How to avoid Infinite loop for trigger in mySQL?
I'm trying to create a trigger in SQL, but the scenario forms a  Infinite loop.
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateTableB
AFTER UPDATE ON tableA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE tableB
   SET info = NEW.data
   WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER UpdateTableA
AFTER UPDATE ON tableB
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE tableA
   SET data = NEW.info
   WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;

What should I do to avoid the loop?
It results Infinite loop.

Why would you do this?  What's the point of having two tables be mirrors of each other?  If one gets damaged, the other one inherits the damage.

What are you trying to do? This sounds like an XY problem.


It results Infinite loop.

NO. You won't obtain infinite loop.
An attempt to update any of these tables will result in Error 1442

Can't update table '%s' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

